# Loss of functionality with keyboard and odd keyboard behavior when using browsers and file management

Tags: keyboard

OS: 20.04.3

Specs:

CPU: Ryzen 5 3600s

GPU: AMD RX 570

Motherboard: Tomahawk b450 MAX

RAM: 16GB ddr4

Keyboard: Reddragon K551

Issue:
Starting about three days ago, sometimes my keyboard will begin lagging, meaning that while I might type extremely fast, the letters don't show on my screen for maybe a full two seconds afterward. Sometimes they'll appear one at a time iteratively, or they'll appear all at once. Other times, they'll not appear at all.

The issue only occurs when using the main functions of the operating system like ctrl+f in my folders or when using any browser (browsers all produce the same issue).

Other loss of functionality is that I can no longer use my arrow keys in order to skip forward or backward in YouTube videos. "j" and "k" keys will only permit me to skip 10 seconds backward or forward respectively one time. I can only do it this one time if I alt-tab out of the browser and alt-tab back in.

When using various websites, even if my input is clearly in the input box (for example, inputting my username), occasionally it will act as if I am outside of the input box, paging down or up, or whatever other alternate function my key-presses might have. Numlock on or off doesn't change this behavior.

Important note: This is produced with two different keyboards of different brands. Both keyboards work completely fine on Windows on the exact same machine. All drivers and other software have been updated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, it happens when the CPU or Memory usage is/are at Max. Can you observe it with a System Monitor, and also happens when the system access a semi-broken hard-drive waiting its spin-up.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka CPU and Memory aren't close to max. Ram is idling at around 30%, CPU less than that.

Comment: What is your file manager? Nemo or Nautilus or something else?

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Nautilus.

Problem occurs on browsers as well. For example, while typing this comment, it paged me down, despite the fact that I didn't misclick anything and didn't use the numbpad. It did this twice.